Error Unauthorized in Azure Logic Apps HTTP
i tried to run a pipline in azure synapse analytics after a blob is added or modified but i get 'Unauthorized' error
i used identity managed as authentification type and i turned on the the system assigned in identity in logic app and i gave synapse contributor role to my logic app in synapse workspace
any help please ?
[enter image description here](https://i.sstatic.netenter image description here/oTxFFo4A.png)enter image description here

You can have a Synapse pipeline trigger directly based on a blob trigger https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/how-to-create-event-trigger?tabs=data-factory. Then you don't need a Logic app. Have you tried this already or is there a reason you can't use this option?

You need to give 2 permissions within the Synapse workspace to your logic app managed identity.

Synapse user


Synapse credential user



You can verify this in the documentation

Once you provide these permissions, your logic app should be able to trigger the Synapse pipeline.
